# How does dirac function satisfy Plancherel's equality?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

As stated in title, how is the following true? $$\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}} |\delta(x)|^2dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}|\hat\delta(t)|^2dt$$.

I know that $\hat\delta =1$, hence the right hand side is infinity but I can't quite make how the left hand side is also the same.

This assertion is listed as an exercise in "Introduction to Applied Mathematics" by Gilbert Strang.

Comment: Neither side makes sense with the usual interpretations. The rhs is a divergent integral. In the lhs, even the integrand is ill-defined. (Plancherel's equality is for $L^2$-functions.)

Comment: I am assuming this exercise is meant to be understood in the distributional sense and also it said the equation allows infinite energy, which I take to mean it includes divergent integrals.

Comment: I can't seem to think of a way of showing that which would not be tautological. If you look at $\delta_0$ as a distribution and try to calculate the integral by looking at its applications to all characters, you get identically the right hand side.

Comment: Even in distributional sense, the left hand side is problematic. You can't really pair $\delta$ with itself in any reasonable way, neither can the product $\delta^2$ be interpreted as a standard distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Compute 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\delta(x)|^2\, dx = +\infty $$ 
by approximation: 
$$
\delta(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon} \zeta\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right),$$
where $\zeta$ is a compactly-supported nonnegative function that integrates to one.

This is not rigorous but it is the usual way to think of the Dirac delta (generalized) function in applied mathematics, AFAIK.